# How to add number of identical line next to the line itself?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, wc

I have file `file.txt` which look like this

```
a
b
b
c
c
c
```

I want to know the command to which get `file.txt` as input and produces the output

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Comment: what is the logic here? to count them? what if they are not ordered? what are your attempts?

Comment: "unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `uniq` is the command you are looking for. The output of `uniq -c` is a little different from your format, but this can be fixed easily.

```
$ uniq -c file.txt
      1 a
      2 b
      3 c
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the occurrences you can use `uniq` with `-c`.

If the file is not sorted you have to use `sort` first

```
$ sort file.txt | uniq -c
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

If you really need the line first followed by the count, swap the columns with `awk`

```
$ sort file.txt | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 " " $1}'
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++{ print $0, (++c) }' file
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

`seen` is an array that holds only uniq items by incrementing to `1` first time an index is populated. In the action we are printing the record and an incrementing counter.

---

**Update:** Based on comment below if intent is to get a **repeat count** in 2nd column then use this awk command:

```
awk 'seen[$0]++{} END{ for (i in seen) print i, seen[i] }' file
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Comment: This won't work, it only appears to work on OP's example because the letters increase by 1 each time, how could you possibly print the number of unique lines before getting to the end of the file ?

Comment: I may not have understood the question and it is not clear if 2nd column is incrementing counter (as I interpreted) or a repeat count

Comment: We don't know what OP requires. Whether just indexing + uniq, or count

Comment: @anubhava Pretty sure from context of the question that it is the number of unique occurences of each line, but I'll retract my downvote for now as i hadn't considered the other interpretation :)

Comment: Thanks, in any case I've added an addendum in my answer to take care of repeat counts (in case).